# Localhost docker Wordpress SMTP gmail configuration issue "Invalid Redirect: must end with a public top-level domain (such as .com or .org)."

Tags: wordpress, docker, woocommerce, smtp, localhost

I'm developing a WP/WC/WCFM marketplace. I need to test my email. So I trying to configure a SMTP with this tutorial: [enter link description here](https://youtu.be/N-hNMOuGh04?t=331). But as I'm using the docker for my local environment setup my link look like this "**http://192.168.99.100:8000**" (do not have the domain yet).

I am receiving this error:
Invalid Redirect: must end with a public top-level domain (such as .com or .org).

Please also see the screen from the gmail page.
[image]

Do you have any idea how to resolve this problem, or at least conduct a mail test from my localhost?

**EDIT:**
Please see below the docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  # Wordpress
  wordpress:
    image: wordpress:latest
    ports:
      - '8000:80'
    restart: always
    volumes: ['./:/var/www/html']
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: WORDPRESS_DB_HOST_SQL
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: 'WORDPRESS_DB_NAME'
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: 'WORDPRESS_DB_USER'
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD
    networks:
      - wpsite
networks:
  wpsite:
```

Comment: can you add the docker command you are using to run the container also?

Comment: Hello @akazuko, the docker is added.

Comment: I have also tried to configure a local redirection under C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\host file. But after adding the domain there the domain it simply doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to resolve this by:

1) Adding an entry in my Windows hosts file for the local IP, located at \Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts:

```
192.168.99.100 xyz xyz.example.com
```

2) Update the wordpress URLs at general setting.

After that everything is going smooth according to above mentioned tutorial.